# domain extension is matter for seo

Tags: seo, domains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does server location or TLD affects SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6519/does-server-location-or-tld-affects-seo)

I would like to buy domain for my blog, while registering the blog i saw the price variations between domain extensions.

Is domain extension is matter for seo.

for example:-

```
.com
.org
.in
etc..
```

Advice me.

Comment: Also see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/does-google-penalize-me-or-tv-sites