# Is there a significant hit to a non .com TLDs exact match domain (EMD) names after Google's Panda update?

Tags: top-level-domains, geolocation, geotargeting, google-panda-algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does server location or TLD affects SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6519/does-server-location-or-tld-affects-seo)

In [this](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/are-exact-match-domains-in-decline) article, there is a good overview of exact match domain names and how they affect SEO after Google's Panda update.

The last graph shows the *Non-com EMD Influence*, where it is suggested that a .com tld will perform better than a non-.com one.

However, let's consider local search.  In the US, .com's work great.  However, let's say you're in Canada, and you have a .ca EMD, all with local, Canadian results.  Would the expectation be that the .com equivalent still perform better?

As a user I would expect the .ca results to be more relevant, and I'm wondering if anyone else has experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

In your case study, I always prefer think with logic unlike SEO.

I think .ca is relevant for business only included Canada but if you decide to extend business to the world, I think .com is better because .com is generic tld (my opinion).

However, difference may be small because SEO depends on many factors. You can get a high SEO level with .com in Canada search results.

Moreover, I like to think non-EMD domain are better than EMD. Indeed, EMD seems to be spammy and non-EMD often refer to a brand.